# Function onLoad in SPA Page

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, reload

I have SPA page, all work very good but when user reload page beeing on winners or garage get info :
**Cannot GET /Garage**. Then have to pick default url. How to set reload function on current page.

https://darogawlik-async-race-api.netlify.app/ (my app)

```
const navigateTo = url => {
    history.pushState(null, null, url)
    router()
}

const router = async () => {
    const routes = [
        { path: '/Garage', view: garage },
        { path: '/Winners', view: winners },
    ]

    // Test each route for potential match
    const potentialMatches = routes.map(route => ({
        route,
        isMatch: location.pathname === route.path,
    }))

    let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatches => potentialMatches.isMatch)

    if (!match) {
        match = {
            route: routes[0],
            isMatch: true,
        }
    }

    const view = new match.route.view(document.querySelector('#main'))
}

window.addEventListener('popstate', router)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (e.target.matches('[data-link]')) {
            e.preventDefault()
            navigateTo(e.target.href)
        }
    })

    router()
})

window.addEventListener('load', router())
```

Comment: poor semicolon feels left out 

Comment: Interesting game  seriously, I like it

Answer (score 0):

This will be a problem with default document handling in the web host - it is not a page load problem. Eg just click this link to get the problem:

- https://darogawlik-async-race-api.netlify.app/Garage

Since you are using path based routing, your web host must serve the default document for all paths, including `/Garage` and `/Winners`. As an example, in Node.js Express you write code like this. For other web hosts you either write similar code or there is a configuration option that will do it for you.

```js
// Serve static content for physical files, eg .js and .css files
expressApp.use('/', express.static());

// Serve the index.html for other paths
expressApp.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile('index.html');
}
```

According to [this post on Netlify](https://coderrob.com/posts/netlify-single-page-app-404-redirect/), you can add a file something like this. I'm no expert on this platform, but hopefully this gives you the info you need to resolve your issue:

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200
```